# Rails app accessible from LAN machine using IP address, but not Bonjour name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, dns, osx-snow-leopard, bonjour

I'm developing a web-based application for iOS devices and want to access it from my Home Screen (via an icon).

I'm able to see the site from an external device by going to http://10.0.1.4:3000, however when I try http://computername.local:3000, Safari fails to load the page.

I've tried visiting both addresses (without the port) where I have another web server running (on port 80 of course) and these both work perfectly fine.

As you've probably already guessed my application is in Rails and I've tried using both Webrick and 'thin' servers to see if it was the server that was at fault, but still not fixed.

Obviously I'd prefer to use the bonjour name, so that I can always access the app from any LAN, regardless of their IP ranges and other settings.

Any suggestions on ways to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "Safari fails to load the page," what exactly do you mean? It can't find the server? Page not found (404)? Server error (500)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I'm using Snow Leopard and **disabling IPv6 was all that was required** for it to work it would seem.

Also of note, publishing the service was **not** required, mainly because it didn't need to be discovered.

Comment: What exactly was preventing Safari from loading your app?

Comment: Not too sure I'm afraid, other than IPv6.  It was so long ago now. Possibly webrick/thin web servers were binding to the IPv4 address and not IPv6, and the other device was trying to connect via IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

Are you advertising a _http._tcp service on port 3000? Check out the mdns command line utility or [Network Beacon](http://www.chaoticsoftware.com/ProductPages/NetworkBeacon.html).

Comment: I didn't have, but now I do and when I type `mdns -B _http._tcp` I have get three occurences of my `Rails Server` and I still can't get to it via my Bonjour name :(

Comment: What does it return? Have you tried using [bonjour browser?](http://www.tildesoft.com/)